# Data bindings do not see viewmodel properties

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

**Problem**:

I am trying to create what seems to be a simple MVVM view setup. However, no matter what I modify, I can't seem to make the PropertyChanged hookup connect to the .xaml and vice-versa.

Here's the View:

**VpicInformationPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ScanditBarcodeScanner.ViewModels"
             x:Class="ScanditBarcodeScanner.Pages.VehicleOperationPages.VpicInformationPage">
    <!--<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:VpicInformationPageViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>-->
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="5">
        <StackLayout.BindingContext>
            <viewModels:VpicInformationPageViewModel />
        </StackLayout.BindingContext>
        <Entry x:Name="VinEntry" Placeholder="VIN (Manual Entry)" />
        <Label Text="{Binding VinType.Make}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding VinType.Model}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding VinType.ModelYear}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding VinType.BodyClass}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding VinType.ErrorCode}" />
        <Button Text="Scan/Check VIN" Clicked="ScanOrCheckVin_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The Model:

**VpicInformationPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using Scandit.BarcodePicker.Unified;
using Scandit.BarcodePicker.Unified.Abstractions;
using ScanditBarcodeScanner.ViewModels;
using ScanditBarcodeScanner.ViewModels.Base;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ScanditBarcodeScanner.Pages.VehicleOperationPages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class VpicInformationPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        IBarcodePicker _picker;

        VpicInformationPageViewModel ViewModel;
        public VpicInformationPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            ViewModel = BindingContext as VpicInformationPageViewModel;

            ViewModel.VinType = VehicleApi.EmptyVinType;

            _picker = ScanditService.BarcodePicker;

            SetVinSettings();

            _picker.DidScan += OnDidScan;

            VinEntry.Text = "";
        }
    //...
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

**VpicInformationPageViewModel.cs**

```
using ScanditBarcodeScanner.ViewModels.Base;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ScanditBarcodeScanner.ViewModels
{
    public class VpicInformationPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region VinType
        private VehicleApi.VinType _vinType;

        public VehicleApi.VinType VinType
        {
            get { return _vinType; }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref _vinType, value, "VinType");
                Make = _vinType.Make;
                Model = _vinType.Model;
                ModelYear = _vinType.ModelYear;
                BodyClass = _vinType.BodyClass;
                ErrorCode = _vinType.ErrorCode;
            }
        }
        #endregion VinType

        #region VinType.Make
        private string _make;
        public string Make
        {
            get { return _vinType.Make; }
            private set
            {
                SetValue(ref _make, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion VinType.Make

        #region VinType.Model
        private string _model;

        public string Model
        {
            get { return _vinType.Model; }
            private set
            {
                SetValue(ref _model, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion VinType.Model

        #region VinType.ModelYear
        private string _modelYear;

        public string ModelYear
        {
            get { return _vinType.ModelYear; }
            private set
            {
                SetValue(ref _modelYear, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion VinType.ModelYear

        #region VinType.BodyClass
        private string _bodyClass;

        public string BodyClass
        {
            get { return _vinType.BodyClass; }
            private set
            {
                SetValue(ref _bodyClass, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion VinType.BodyClass

        #region VinType.ErrorCode
        private string _errorCode;

        public string ErrorCode
        {
            get { return _vinType.ErrorCode; }
            private set
            {
                SetValue(ref _errorCode, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion VinType.ErrorCode

        public VpicInformationPageViewModel()
        {
            _vinType = new VehicleApi.VinType();
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModelBase:

**ViewModelBase.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ScanditBarcodeScanner.ViewModels.Base
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        protected bool SetValue<T>(ref T BackingField, T Value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            if(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(BackingField, Value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            BackingField = Value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I realized that I didn't include the `VehicleApi` class. Here is the important part of that class:

**VehicleApi.cs**

```
namespace ScanditBarcodeScanner
{
    public static class VehicleApi
    {
        public static VinType EmptyVinType { get; } = new VinType
        {
            Make = "Make",
            Model = "Model",
            ModelYear = "Model Year",
            BodyClass = "Body Class",
            ErrorCode = "Status/Error Code"
        };

        public class VinType
        {
            public string Make { get; set; }
            public string Model { get; set; }
            public string ModelYear { get; set; }
            public string BodyClass { get; set; }
            public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
        }
}
```

It is my understanding that I have implemented these files correctly and linked them together properly. However, every time I run the app, I get:

`[0:] Binding: 'VinType' property not found on 'ScanditBarcodeScanner.ViewModels.VpicInformationPageViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'`

I have bound the View to the ViewModel, and implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I have tried many solutions, such as changing where I set the binding context (either in the ContentPage or in the StackLayout, or even both), trying different methods of notifying the view that properties have changed, and binding the labels to the underlying members of `VinType`, and allowing `VinType` to modify and raise PropertyChanged for them.  I even tried PropertyChanged.Fody, but it seems the issue is not with the notifying code, but with the way I have bound the View and ViewModel together, or perhaps with how the properties are defined.

**Question:**

What part of the binding hookup is missing/incorrect? The documentation states that I should just be able to access `VinType` and its members with the code I have provided.

[Link to sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/orjodhdi7gn6u6y/BindingSampleApp.zip?dl=0)

The issue with the project above, is that, while it doesn't give the same error I'm talking about, it still doesn't change the fields when it's supposed to.

Comment: I create some code to test, but it works fine and have no issue, so can you provide one simple that can reproduce your issue at github, then share the link here?

Comment: what is the purpose of using TwoWay binding on a Label?

Comment: @Jason I don't actually need TwoWay binding, so I've removed that.

Comment: The `ScanditBarcodeScanner.ViewModels.VpicInformationPageViewModel` class you posted clearly does have a public `VinType` property, so the only way the error message can make sense is that the context object at runtime is some _other_ version of the `ScanditBarcodeScanner.ViewModels.VpicInformationPageViewModel` class. Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to answer the question, but it looks like you probably just have an old/different version of the DLL where that class lives being used at runtime. Try a clean build, make sure you have the right version.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with the Xamarin dialect of XAML, but in WPF/WinRT/etc. the syntax `VinType.Make`, `VinType.Model`, etc. would be correct only if the `VehicleApi.VinType` class has those properties. From the wrapper properties in your view model, it seems like it _should_ (and the error would be different in any case, if that were really the problem). But since you do have the wrapper properties, why not just bind to those, instead of to the `VinType` version? Does the `VinType` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have actually tried that, and I get the same error, except instead of ```VinType``` being the problem, now the properties are the problem (e.g., ```Make```, ```Model```, etc). Also, ```VinType``` doesn't implement ```INotifyPropertyChanged```, but my ```ViewModelBase``` does, which ```VpicInformationPageViewModel``` inherits from.

Comment: _"`VinType` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`"_ -- to be clear, failing to implement INPC won't prevent binding. It will only prevent updates to the bound property when the source property changes. But, do keep that in mind if/when you've fixed the more basic binding issue. _"I have actually tried that, and I get the same error"_ -- trust the error. Somehow, some way, you are using for the binding context a version of that type without those properties, i.e. _not_ the code you posted here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I tried deleting `bin` and `obj` folders, cleaning, and I even wrote code that I have tested in a new solution, that does work. Then I made new files in my current solution for that new code. It no longer gives me the error but the text still doesn't show for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the fix to this issue was actually something rather simple.

I just needed to change the label definitions from
`<Label Text="{Binding PropertyName.Member}" />` to `<Label Text="{Binding PropertyName.Member, StringFormat='{}{0}'}">`

The reason there needs to be the `{}` in the format string is because of an error that comes up when you use single quotes `''` instead of double quotes `""` when defining StringFormat.

EDIT: While the StringFormat issue is important, the larger issue is that the properties in the objects I was using did not have `get` or `set` defined.
As long as a Type is something along the lines of this:

```
public class TypeName
{
    public Type Property1 { get; set; }
    public Type Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then the binding engine will be able to see and edit the member properties.